# Unable to find image 'acbuild:latest' locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

I'm attempting to compile Stygian's repack of AzerothCore as I want to add the Auction House Bot module. I have installed and set up Docker, cloned the repo and installed the module and patch, but I am receiving an error while trying to run the "./bin/acore-docker-build" command as outlined in the wiki.

I am running Windows 10 Pro

I have run the following commands:

```
./bin/acore-docker-generate-etc
```

Which appeared to work, and

```
./bin/acore-docker-build
```

Which produced the following error:

> scott@DESKTOP-BGVSVR4 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Stygian/StygianCore/Source
>   (master) $ ./bin/acore-docker-build unable to prepare context: unable
>   to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx
>   C:\Users\scott\Desktop\Stygian\StygianCore\Source\docker\build: The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Unable to find image
>   'acbuild:latest' locally C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from
>   daemon: pull access denied for acbuild, repository does not exist or
>   may require 'docker login'. See 'C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

Answer (score 1):

Repacks are not supported by AC. You are probably using an older version of AC and not the latest.

You are getting the error:

> Unable to find image 'acbuild:latest'

but in the latest version of AC, such image is baked in the same script that you're trying to run (`./bin/acore-docker-build`) and its Dockerfile is located in `docker/build/Dockerfile`.

Try to clone AC from [the official repository](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) and it will work.